# Is "bankroll" preferred to "fund" as a verb in formal writing?

Tags: american-english, word-usage, connotation, nuance

In formal, factual writing, is it more appropriate to use as a verb the word "fund" rather than "bankroll"? [Example: "An anonymous donor [bankrolls/funds] the food pantry."]

To me, "bankroll" has a slightly unsavory connotation that "fund" doesn't. If the context is simply to provide factual information, would "fund" be a better choice, or am I being too sensitive?

Comment: "Bankroll", as a verb, is not a formal term.

Comment: There are many ways to fund a project; a bankroll is only one of them.

Comment: ODO, for example, adds an 'informal' caveat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Oxford dictionary, *bankroll* is used informally. (Although there is no mention of any kind of negative connotation.)

Therefore, using another word (such as *fund*, *finance*, *subsidize*, or *endow*) would be better in formal writing.